# LookAroundPreview for SwiftUI MapKit - does lookAroundViewer exist?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm having fun with SwiftUI's new MapKit capabilities, and I love how simple a `LookAroundPreview` is to create. But the documentation claims that there is a

`.lookAroundViewer(isPresented: $isLookingAround, initialScene: lookAroundScene)`

method that can be applied to existing views, and... well, it's not there - at least the compiler doesn't think so. To be clear, the documentation says:

> To display a Look Around viewer a person can explore, apply a lookAroundViewer view modifier to a specific view, then add a control the user interacts with to display the Look Around viewer. In the following example, the lookAroundViewer view modifier observes a binding to Boolean value to determine whether to display the Look Around viewer.

Now, I *have* a static `LookAroundPreview` working (and man that's great, for so little effort), but I think the documentation is a little ahead of itself...

My question is "has `.lookAroundViewer(isPresented: $isLookingAround, initialScene: lookAroundScene)` actually been implemented in Xcode 15b3, and if so, how do I invoke it?".

Many thanks. Here's the working code...

```
    @State private var lookAroundScene: MKLookAroundScene?
    @State private var isLookingAround = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            item.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                //.lookAroundViewer(isPresented: $isLookingAround, initialScene: lookAroundScene) //<--- DOESN'T WORK
            if lookAroundScene.exists {
                Button(systemImage: "binoculars") { isLookingAround = true }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: getLookAroundScene)
        .popover(isPresented: $isLookingAround) {
            LookAroundPreview(initialScene: lookAroundScene)
        }
    }
    
    private func getLookAroundScene() {
        lookAroundScene = nil
        Task {
            let request = MKLookAroundSceneRequest(coordinate: item.coordinate)
            lookAroundScene = try? await request.scene
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work now.

- With your commented code, the LookaroundPreview opens in a mid-size view.
- When the `.lookAroundViewer` line is uncommented, the view becomes fullscreen after touching. If you comment the second `LookaroundPreview`, the first one seems to miss an important initialization and the fullscreen preview appears but is empty.

Full code: https://gist.github.com/thadk/ea2e067b246b3bf7d96b94115da1f846